# Get apple developer key

Tags: ios, cordova

I've get apple devloper account specially for phonegap build. Is there any way ta get sigin key to upload phonegap build without mac and xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Upload requires a unique sign key that can only be used by xcode on the mac

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the MAC closed world. You can try to virtualize an OS X or whatever, but if you intend to upload to the App Store... you have to do it through a MAC

Answer (score 0):

I could not try it but using OpenSSL it should work with Windows AS well: http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/11/phonegap/building-an-ios-signing-key-for-phonegap-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is old news, but you can create the certificate and provisioning needed on Apple Developer site now.  The PhoneGap have nice detailed instructions. http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.1.0/signing_signing-ios.md.html